# Huge reserved memory according to DebugDial (memory leak?)

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks, debugdiag

We experience memory problems in production.

On the 2008 Windows Server there are many web api services. I see that most of them have the same problem(?) which is quite a big number as reserved memory.
Below are informations from one othe services which I got using DebugDiag.
The service uses Linq2Sql, another WebApi service, FileSystem only to write to LogFile, and sends Email.

**.NET GC Heap Information**

GC Heap Size 84,77 MBytes
Total Commit Size  153 MB

**Total Reserved Size    17254 MB**

**Virtual Memory Summary**

Size of largest free VM block   7,97 TBytes

Free memory fragmentation   0,11%

Free Memory   7,98 TBytes   (99,79% of Total Memory)

Reserved Memory   17,03 GBytes   (0,21% of Total Memory)

Committed Memory   384,59 MBytes   (0% of Total Memory)

Total Memory   8 TBytes

Largest free block at   0x00000005`3f380000

**Virtual Memory Details**

Virtual Allocations  17,19 GBytes

Loaded Modules  179,97 MBytes

Threads  17,27 MBytes

System 4 KBytes

Page Heaps 0 Bytes

Native Heaps  28,76 MBytes

**Virtual Allocation Summary**

Reserved memory   17 GBytes

Committed memory   185,82 MBytes

Mapped memory   15,5 MBytes

Reserved block count   94 blocks

Committed block count   129 blocks

Mapped block count   30 blocks

In **Resource Monitor** I have following informations:

Commited: 257 MB

Working 394 MB

Private 198 MB

Should I ignore this information about reserved memory or it tells me something really important?

I would be grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved memory refers to **VIRTUAL MEMORY** used by a process. This is something that you can check by viewing the **Virtual Bytes** perfmon counter. I don't think task manager still has a column that shows this information. If you Sysinternals tools like Process Explorer or VMMap, you can see the virtual bytes used by the process and that should be close to what Debugdiag is showing you as the RESERVED memory.

Starting .NET Framework 4.5 (I think) and especially on 64 bit OS, CLR reserves a HUGE chunk of memory (because it is virtual and not physical). For e.g. 4.5 asp.net application on a 8 proc box running in x64 mode - the initial reserved memory will be as high as **18GB**. This is totally expected and not a problem at all.